# How do I sort/copy an array using pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, copy

I am trying to sort and copy an array using only `<algorithm>`, but cannot figure out how to accomplish either.  This is the code I have been trying to make work, but with no success.  What am I missing?

```
sorted_sc_array(const sorted_sc_array& A);          
template< sorted_sc_array& A, sorted_sc_array& T>   
auto Copy(sorted_sc_array& A, sorted_sc_array& T)   
    ->signed char*(T.begin())   
{  
  auto it1=std::begin(A);  
  auto it2=std::begin(T);

  while(it1 != std::end(A)){
    *it2++ = *it1++;
  }
  return it2;
}
```

Comment: `->signed char*(T.begin())`. How does this even compile?

Comment: does `std::sort` and `std::copy` not work?

Comment: @Angew oh it throws a bunch of errors

Comment: @NathanOliver how do I use those? (I've read about them, just don't get how I could use them with pointers)

Comment: Well for the most part `pointers == iterators` so you just use them like you would iterators on a standard container.  Hint: begin points to the first element and end points to one past the last element.

Comment: It seems you might find following a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) useful.

Answer (score 1):

To sort an array:

```
const unsigned int CAPACITY = 1024;
int array[CAPACITY];
//...
std::sort(&array[0], &array[CAPACITY]);
```

To copy an array:

```
int destination[CAPACITY];
//...
std::copy(&array[0], &array[CAPACITY], &destination[0]);
```

Addresses can be substituted for pointers or iterators in most functions in `<algorithm>`.

**With Pointers**

```
int * p_begin = &array[0];
int * p_end   = &array[CAPACITY];
//...
std::sort(p_begin, p_end);
//...
int * p_dest_begin = &destination[0];
std::copy(p_begin, p_end, p_dest_begin);
```